# Table results within loops

Tags: list-manipulation

I have the following code.

```
n = 0;
For[iii = 0, iii < Nn, iii++,

z = -L + iii*h;

While[
            n < Nn - 1, 
            xn = -L + h*n;
            result = result + func[z,xn];
             n++;
     ]
(* Store (z, result *)
result = 0;
n = 0;
]
```

The function *func* is predefined and the constants *Nn*, *h*, *L* as well. My question is: how do I store the results obtained in the loop in a list? I would like to do this at the point where I commented "(* Store (z, result) )*". Ultimately I would like to use this list to make a listplot.

I have looked at previous questions where the answers almost always say that one should use 'reap' and 'saw', but I don't see how one should use this here, as I explicitly need to put result back to zero after each step

Comment: [*Death to loops!*](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7924/alternatives-to-procedural-loops-and-iterating-over-lists-in-mathematica) :P  [Seriously, the linked question has some suggestions for alternative approaches.]

Comment: `Sow[result];result=0`  of course using `Table` instead of `For` would be far better.

Comment: @george2079 I tried using a table but I just could not get it to work.

Comment: it should look like `Table[result=0;While[];result,{iii,Nn}]`

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try the following construct, which replaces the iterative code with *Mathematica* constructs and reduces the need for many of the variables:

```
Table[Sum[func[iii*h-L,h*n-L],{n,0,Nn-1}],{iii,0,Nn-1}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this problem from a view of list you can do this the Mathematica way.

First set up your constants.

```
(* ClearAll["Global`*"] *)
nSteps = 20;  h = 0.5; l = 2; (* Nn = nSteps and L = l, don't start with capitals *)
```

`z` and `nx` are just list that are combined a few times.  Start by creating these list.

```
z = -l +#*h& /@ Range[0, nSteps-1, 1]
nx = -l+h*#& /@ Range[0, nSteps-2, 1]
```

Next we need a function that will do the action in the `While`.  I don't know what your `func` does so I'm just going to make one that multiplies the `z` item across the `nx` list and `Total`s them up.  You need the `Total`part but can make it do what you need inside instead of multiplying through.

```
func[x_Real, y_List] := Total[x*y]
```

You can check this works by picking the fist `z` and passing it into `func` with `nx`.

```
func[z[[1]],nx]
```

Now to get them all we can just `Map` the `func` across all the `z` items while pairing the `z` item with its result

```
{#,func[#,nx]}& /@ z
```

Hope this has helped.

Comment: I just noticed you need a `0` step.  In that case change to `Range[0,nSteps,1]` and `Range[0,nSteps-1,1]` to get the `0` step. I'll update the above.